# Legal restrictions for EU-foreigners to setup bank account in Czech republic

Tags: bank-account

Are there any legal restrictions for setting up a bank account for a EU-foreigner in Czech republic who is not having a seat of residence in Czech republic?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly do you mean by "seat of residence". That term has different meanings (legally) in different countries and different contexts.

If you're foreigner (even from within the EU), any czech bank will most likely ask you to provide a residence permit.

Here are some details:

http://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/third-country-nationals-long-term-residence.aspx

http://www.czech.cz/en/Business/How-it-works-here/Making-business/How-to-open-a-bank-account-%E2%80%93-Part-1